# Prevent magento 2 from empty the cart after cancel/fail payments

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, payment

How to prevent Magento 2.1 from emptying cart after canceled or failed payments?

When I cancel a payment the cart is empty, and I need to prevent this behaviour.

There are a lot of solutions for 1.9, but I've found nothing for magento2, I've seen even answers about solutions in magento 1.9 for questions about magento2, but not a solution for magento2.

Is there any solution for magento 2.1?

Comment: Hi. Did you find something useful?

Comment: not yet, still clearing cart when cancelling a payment.

Answer (score 1):

For **Magento 2.3.5**, Below is the solution. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change ***public function*** as below

```
public function execute()
{
   
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```